# Changing css display element after document.ready jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am testing new menu code and one problem with it, is that it loads everything, then jumps into place when all finished loading.

So what i'm trying is to hide it until the document is ready and then show it

So, CSS to hide it:

```
#mega-menu-1 {
font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif; 
list-style: none; 
position: relative; 
padding: 0; 
margin: 0;
margin-top:13px;
display: none;
}
```

Then I'm calling the jquery at the end of the page to load the menu, then change the display to block, but menu not displaying

Here's the jquery I'm trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#mega-menu-1').dcMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '2',
            event: 'click',
            fullWidth: false
        });
        $('#mega-menu-1').css('display') == 'block';
    });
</script>
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to set the `display` property then you have wrong syntax for jQuery function [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/), you need `css( propertyName , value)` to set property value.

*Change*

```
$('#mega-menu-1').css('display') == 'block';
```

*To*

```
$('#mega-menu-1').css('display', 'block') ;
```

**OR** You can also call jQuery [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method that will do the same.

```
$('#mega-menu-1').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#mega-menu-1').dcMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '2',
            event: 'click',
            fullWidth: false
        });
        $('#mega-menu-1').show();
    });
</script>
```

[reference website](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the "dcMegaMenu" plugin just loaded from extern source (a JS-file). Try this, it helped me once in another project:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $('#mega-menu-1').dcMegaMenu({
            rowItems: '2',
            event: 'click',
            fullWidth: false
        });
        $(document).find('#mega-menu-1').css({'display' : 'block'});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made you a [jsFiddle test page](http://jsfiddle.net/7JQvz/) where your menu get displayed.

A minor update in the display value change, but also I have commented out your .dcMegaMenu statement (cause you don't give any information about it). And if you still have the issue is probably because it fails on this one.

```
$('#mega-menu-1').css('display', 'block');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

#### It is jQuery Syntax, not JavaScript

Replace:

```
$('#mega-menu-1').css('display') == 'block';
```

With:

```
$('#mega-menu-1').css('display', 'block');
```

#### And if you want to use getters and setters:

**Set:** `$('#mega-menu-1').css('display', 'block');`

**Get:** `$('#mega-menu-1').css('display');`

**Compare:** `$('#mega-menu-1').css('display') == "block"`